# Maven: Could not find goal 'create' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a Web Application Project with Maven as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-archetype-plugin-1.0-alpha-7/examples/webapp.html) but I keep getting the following error

```
mvn archetype:create 
    -DgroupId=ru.jofsey 
    -DartifactId=example 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp 
    -DinteractiveMode=false
    -e

[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.373 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-18T14:31:49+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'create' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0 among available goals crawl, create-from-project, generate, help, integration-test, jar, update-local-catalog -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoNotFoundException: Could not find goal 'create' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0 among available goals crawl, create-from-project, generate, help, integration-test, jar, update-local-catalog
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Comment: You need to use `archetype:generate` instead of `archetype:create`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As per the following [release note](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/02/12/apache-maven-archetype-plugin-version-3-dot-0-0-released/), the plugin has removed support for the `archetype-create` goal. It was already marked as deprecated in recent versions of the plugin, and instead you should use the `archetype:generate` goal. The Jira issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-437) mentions the following:

> It's time to finally remove the support for the old create goal. For users still using it, it should fail the build with a message about using the generate goal instead.

The [plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/) also removed any mentioning of `archetype:create`.

Answer (score 0):

Using mvn archetype:generate instance of mvn archetype:create

```
mvn archetype:generate
```